# Why the differential of exponential map is the identity.

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ a manifold and $T_pM$ it's tangent plan at $p$. We defined 
\begin{align*}
\exp_p:U_p\subset \Omega _p&\longrightarrow M\\
V&\longmapsto \gamma _V(1)
\end{align*}
where $\gamma _V:I_V\longrightarrow M$ is a geodesic s.t.

1) $\gamma _V(0)=p$,

2) $\dot\gamma_V(0)=V$,

3) $I_V\subset \mathbb R$ is an interval that contain $0$ and $1$.

and $\gamma _V$ is maximal for 1) and 2). And $\Omega _p=\{V\in T_pM\mid 1\in I_V\}.$

**Question 1 :** First of all,what does mean "$\gamma _V$ is maximal for 1) and 2)" ? What does it mean ?

**Question 2 :** Then, I don't understand why $$\mathrm d _0\exp_p=id.$$

To me if $f\in \mathcal C^\infty (M)$, then $$\mathrm d _0 f(V)=V(f)$$
where $V\in T_pM$. But how it work here ?

Answer (score 3):

**Q1)** It's says that if there is a geodesic $\tilde\gamma :I_W\longrightarrow M$ s.t. $\gamma (0)=p$ and $\dot\gamma (0)=V$, then $\gamma_V|_{I_W}=\tilde \gamma $.

**Q2)** You should have proved somewhere that $\Omega _p$ is star shaped (in $0$), and that $\gamma _V(t)=\exp(tV)$ (which is well defined by the fact that $\Omega _p$ is star shaped). Now, let $V\in \Omega _p$. 
$$(\mathrm d _0\exp_p)(V):=V\exp_p\underset{(*)}{=}\left.\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d t}\right|_{t=0}\exp(tV)=\left.\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d t}\right|_{t=0}\gamma _V(t)=\dot\gamma (0)=V.$$
Therefore, it's the identity.

Just a justification for $(*)$: It comes from the fact that $\Omega _p$ is star-shaped (in $0$). And thus, every vector of $\Omega _p$ is of the form $0+Vt=Vt$.